# A Better inline javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to write this code? i tried function(){}(); but i got an error so i had to use DUMMY as a placeholder var. The function should run before alert b does. Whats  a better way of writing this?

```
var DUMMY = function(){
    var names = "i dont want to be seen";
    alert('A');
}; DUMMY();

alert('B');
```

Comment: @Amnon: Nothing. I put it to make it more clear for certain people who may notice both alerts and understand i desire the function to be ran before that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually use the syntax you say doesn't work all the time.  The thing is, you need to either store the return value, or make it an expression.  So either:

```
var foo = function() { return false; }();
```

or

```
(function() { return false; }());
```

Note the difference between Pointy's answer on this one.  The expression is the entire function (including the calling `()`), not just the function declaration.  Either way will do the same thing.  Use what you feel is more readable (Personally I like this syntax better, but to each their own)...

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses to make it look like an expression:

```
(function() { alert("hi"); })();
```

I recently saw this (at the TXJS conference):

```
!function() { alert("hi"); }();
```

The leading "!" serves the same purpose: the parser sees an expression instead of a function definition statement.

Comment: Nice hack! In fact, you can use any unary operator. So maybe `void function() { alert("hi"); }()` is a little bit less confusing.

Comment: Well yes that works, but in all honesty that's the first time I've ever seen "void" used in Javascript, and I've been doing this for a while :-)  Confusion is in the mind of the beholder!

Answer (score 2):

For now the best is

```
(()=>{})()
```

or even

```
!()=>{}
```